# Change callback name returned from react hook

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, usesound

I want to use  stop function in useSound Hooks in diffrent name because I alredy used stop variable.

[Use Sound Doc](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound)

```js
import play from "./assets/play.mp3";

const [Phone,{stopPhone as stop }] = useSound(phone);
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. If you want to change the name of a variable, you can. A variable stores a value Ex: ``x = 1``.that can also be written as ``y = 1``, the name of the variable is almost always the programmer's choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Object desctructoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) like so:

```js
const [Phone, { stop: stopPhone }] = useSound(phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If useSound returns an array, there should be no need to "rename" any of its items - simply put in the names you want into the destructuring syntax:

```
const [Phone,stopPhone] = useSound(phone);
```

you can simply choose whatever names you wish.

If it returns an object you can use object destructuring as follows

```
const [Phone,{ stop: stopPhone }] = useSound(phone);
```

Comment: Second element in returned array is [an object with callbacks](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound#exposeddata)

Comment: i have updated the answer. check now @BANOnotIT